# calling arrayfun; parameter estimation;

Tags: function, matlab, handle

I have a problem with estimation.

I  have a function, which is dependent on the values of an unknown vector V = [v1, …, v4].
I also have a vector of reference data YREF = [yref1, …, yrefn].
I would like to write a function, which returns the vector Y (in order to compare it later, say using lsqnonlin). I am aware of the “arrayfun”, but it seems not to work.

I have a subfunction, which returns a concrete value from the range [-100, 100],

```
 %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 function y = SubFunction(Y, V)
  y = fzero(@(x) v(1).*sinh(x./v(2)) + v(3).*x - Y, [-100 100]);
 end
 %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

then I make some operations on the results:

```
 %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 function y = SomeFunction(Y,V)
  temp = SubFunction (Y,V);
  y = temp + v(4).*Y;
 end
 %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

These functions work well for a single value of Y, but not for the whole vector. How to store the results into a matrix for future comparison?

Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0):

If `Y` is a vector, then the anonymous function defined as an argument to `fzero` returns a vector, not a scalar.

You can solve it by using a loop (notice the `Y(k)` inside the anonymous function definition):

```
 function y = SubFunction(Y, v)
     y = zeros (size(Y));
     for k = 1 : length (Y)
         y(k) = fzero(@(x) v(1).*sinh(x./v(2)) + v(3).*x - Y(k), [-100 100]);
     end
 end
```